# How to stop for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, each

I am new to VBA. I am trying to make a `for each` loop that gives me the position of a value where `x=y`, but I keep getting the position of the last `Y` in my statement `(C10)`. I hope someone can help me.
Kind regards

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
        Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C10")
        For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then y.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    x.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    x.Offset(0, 3).Value = y.Address

        Next y

   x.Offset(0, 5).Select



        Next x

End Sub
```

this is what I want.

```
A       B       C       D
1   1   5   $C$4
2       4   
3   3   6   $C$6
4   4   1   $C$2
5   5   9   $C$1
6   6   3   $C$3
7       75  
8       12  
9   9   55  $C$5
10      90  
11          
12  12      $C$8
```

and this is what I get...

```
A       B       C       D
1   1   5   $C$10
2       4   $C$10
3   3   6   $C$10
4   4   1   $C$10
5   5   9   $C$10
6   6   3   $C$10
7       75  $C$10
8       12  $C$10
9   9   55  $C$10
10      90  $C$10
11          $C$10
12  12      $C$10
```

Comment: You should only use the `Variant` data type when absolutely necessary. Just declare your variables properly, eg. `Dim CompareRange as Range, x as range, y as range`. Also, `x` and `y` are not really good variable names. See some [best practices](http://spreadsheetsuperstar.com/excel-vba-best-practices-variables/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if x=y then exit for
```

Also, you want to copy x, not the selection.

Here is your code

```
    Sub Find_Matches()

Range("A1:A12").Select

Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C10")

For Each x In Selection

    For Each y In CompareRange

        If x = y Then

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            x.Copy
            x.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            x.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            x.Offset(0, 3).value = y.Address

        Exit For

        End If

    Next y

    x.Offset(0, 5).Select

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: thx for the code, but it doesn't produce the desired output. It just give me a random value and doesn't paste any format neither. Do you have any other Ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of your data and the desired output?

Comment: I am selecting Row A and then run script.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why column B isn't coming out the way you want, but this will at least give you the correct address (and run faster). You were only selecting y if x = y, but I imagine you only wanted to do the rest of the lines if x = y. So putting that all in the if statement works to make your lines stay empty if there is no match.

Comment: The reason why I am coping y and not x is because y has a color format I desire in "B" that x doesn't have. With other words it is doing what I want, but is not coping the format of y into cell B.

Comment: So, you want the value of x, but the format of y? If that's so, then change `x.copy` to `y.copy` and put `x.copy` between the paste lines.

Comment: I used y.copy, and it is working perfectly. Thank you for your help. 1 question was it the end if that did the trick or   not using " x.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats"?

Comment: No problem. Just mark it as accepted so others know you're not still waiting to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Exit For` statement to break out of a loop when your condition is satisfied.